# finding blocks of memory

Tags: c, valgrind, free

Is there any way how to find out where the person forgot to `free()` memory?

Valgrind only says how many allocs and frees there were but not where the person didnt free when he should have. Is there any way how to find out the piece of memory that should be freed?

Comment: Are you running Valgrind with `--track-origins=yes`?

Comment: Valgrind can tell you where the block was *allocated*, but deciding where it should be freed is a decision the programmer has to make.

Comment: If vylgrind could determine where a block should be `free`ed, it possibly solved the Halting Problem. **Please** (please!) instantly tell us if you find such a tool.

Comment: @Olaf there could be such a tool, it would just take infinitely long to run :>

Comment: @M.M: That's a secondary problem ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that what you would like is to have valgrind reporting an error
when you 'lose' the last pointer to a piece of memory.

valgrind does not have such a functionality. There used to be an experimental
tool doing that (--tool=omega), but it is not (anymore?) in the valgrind
repository, IIUC, because there was many false positive and/or false negative.

The closest you can do is to use valgrind + gdb (via vgdb), and put
some breakpoints at various places in your program, and do a leak search
at all these places. With a kind of 'dichotomic' search, you might find
the place where you lose the pointer.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver
and http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands
for more details about using gdb with valgrind and doing interactive
leak searches.